# Leiningen uberjar "empty" running time

Tags: clojure

After creating a uberjar with leiningen, and running the jar with `java -jar foo-uberjar.jar` the program runs fine, and the last line of code is executed quite fast, but the program hangs for about a minute before shutting down. What is the cause of this?

```
(ns redditwallpaper.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.contrib.duck-streams :as duck]
            [clojure.java [io :as io] [shell :as shell]]
            [clojure.string :as string]
            [clojure.contrib.json :as json])
  (:import (java.util Random)))

(defn filename [uri]
  (last (string/split uri #"/")))
(defn over_18 [x]
  (:over_18 x))
(defn posts [x]
  (map :data (get-in x [:data :children])))
(defn plain-image [x]
  (re-find #"(.jpg|.png)$" (:url x)))
(def url "http://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper.json")
(def wallpaperjson (json/read-json (slurp url)))
(defn copy [uri fname]
  (with-open [in (io/input-stream uri)
              out (io/output-stream fname)]
    (.write out (duck/to-byte-array in))))
(defn randrange [n]
  (.nextInt (Random.) n))
(defn randitem [xs]
  (let [n (count xs)]
    (nth xs (randrange n))))
(defn set-background [file]
  (shell/sh "feh" "--bg-scale" file))
(defn -main [& args]
  (let [posts (posts wallpaperjson)
        safe (filter (complement over_18) posts)
        images (filter plain-image safe)
        image (:url (randitem images))
        fname (filename image)]
    (do
      (println (format "Downloading '%s'" image))
      (copy image fname)
      (println (format "Setting background image to '%s'" fname))
      (set-background fname)
      (println "Done"))))
```

`java -jar redditwallpaper-0.0.1-standalone.jar  2.71s user 0.34s system 4% cpu 1:03.15 total`

Comment: Might there be a daemon thread lurking around?

Comment: That's all the code. If there is, how could I go finding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding,

```
(shutdown-agents)
```

when you are ready to exit.

Comment: Because `clojure.java.shell/sh` needs to start up a future or an agent or something in order to prevent deadlocking on reading the process's input.

Comment: amalloy could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Masse: agents are run on a thread pool, as long as that thread pool is running jvm won't exit. shutdown-agents will shutdown the thread pool when no threads remain jvm will exit.

Comment: @Hamza rather, if that situation comes up again, how am I able to know "AHA! It's <function>"

Comment: AFAIK there is no way, it could be any function, or any function in any third party lib that uses agents.

Comment: This is just a limitation of Clojure; it doesn't provide enough flexibility over the thread pools it creates. See http://tech.puredanger.com/2010/06/08/clojure-agent-thread-pools/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed in in my experiments with bash/clojure interop that a better way might be to simply use the [lein-exec](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec) plugin, for a couple of reasons.

First off, it works well for me so far.

I also ran a couple of time commands from bash to get a feeling for the difference between my original idea - which was basically to make a lein template for scripts - on the one hand, and lein-exec on the other.

On the one hand, my experiment. I hadn't made a lein template yet, but the idea was this:

```
(ns closcrite.core
  (:require [clojure.java.shell :as shell])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot."
  [& args]
  (let [shell-output (apply shell/sh args)]
    (println (shell-output :out))
    (shutdown-agents)))
```

The `(shutdown-agents)` sexpr is simply because I ran into this problem.
Without `(shutdown-agents)`:

```
lein compile && lein uberjar 
  && time java -jar target/closcrite-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar "ls" "-ahl"
Compiling closcrite.core
Compilation succeeded.
All namespaces already :aot compiled.
Created /home/j/Development/closcrite/target/closcrite-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including closcrite-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including clojure-1.4.0.jar
Created /home/j/Development/closcrite/target/closcrite-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
total 36K
drwxrwxr-x  6 j j 4.0K Aug 18 18:14 .
drwxrwxr-x 26 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 doc
-rw-rw-r--  1 j j   99 Aug 18 17:55 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 j j  325 Aug 18 18:14 project.clj
-rw-rw-r--  1 j j  199 Aug 18 17:55 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  3 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 src
drwxrwxr-x  4 j j 4.0K Aug 18 18:02 target
drwxrwxr-x  3 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 test


real    1m2.585s
user    0m4.188s
sys     0m0.120s
```

With `(shutdown-agents)`:

```
lein compile && lein uberjar 
    && time java -jar target/closcrite-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar "ls" "-ahl"                                                                
Compiling closcrite.core
Compilation succeeded.
All namespaces already :aot compiled.
Created /home/j/Development/closcrite/target/closcrite-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including closcrite-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including clojure-1.4.0.jar
Created /home/j/Development/closcrite/target/closcrite-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
total 36K
drwxrwxr-x  6 j j 4.0K Aug 18 18:14 .
drwxrwxr-x 26 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 doc
-rw-rw-r--  1 j j   99 Aug 18 17:55 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 j j  325 Aug 18 18:14 project.clj
-rw-rw-r--  1 j j  199 Aug 18 17:55 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  3 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 src
drwxrwxr-x  4 j j 4.0K Aug 18 18:02 target
drwxrwxr-x  3 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 test


real    0m2.817s
user    0m3.796s
sys     0m0.084s
```

On the other hand, lein-exec:

```
      time lein exec -e "(ns blah 
                             (:require [clojure.java.shell :as shell])) 
                         (print ((shell/sh \"ls\" \"-ahl\") :out))"
    total 36K
    drwxrwxr-x  6 j j 4.0K Aug 18 18:14 .
    drwxrwxr-x 26 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 ..
    drwxrwxr-x  2 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 doc
    -rw-rw-r--  1 j j   99 Aug 18 17:55 .gitignore
    -rw-rw-r--  1 j j  325 Aug 18 18:14 project.clj
    -rw-rw-r--  1 j j  199 Aug 18 17:55 README.md
    drwxrwxr-x  3 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 src
    drwxrwxr-x  4 j j 4.0K Aug 18 18:02 target
    drwxrwxr-x  3 j j 4.0K Aug 18 17:55 test

    real    0m1.371s
    user    0m2.136s
    sys     0m0.120s
```

Of course `time` isn't the be-all end-all in profiling, but it's a nice indication of speed. For the user the inline lein-exec shell script feels almost 2x as fast as the code I used to model the execution time of a minimal leiningen shell script template.